# Akka actor is processing the second message before processing the first message

Tags: scala, akka

I am learning and understanding Akka actor model with some basic examples.

I created two instances for a same Actor (i.e) "helloworld1" and "helloworld2" and sending messages to that Actor. The first message is sent by instance "helloworld1" and second message is sent by "helloworld2" .

When i run the below code i get output as below

```
Yes you made it Hi helloworld2
Yes you made it Hi helloworld1
```

My question is why is it the 2nd message is processed at first? I was expecting the output as below because the first message is sent by helloworld1

```
Yes you made it Hi helloworld1
Yes you made it Hi helloworld2
```

**Code for ActorApp:**

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}

object ActorApp {

 def main(args :Array[String]) ={

 val system = ActorSystem("SimpleActorSystem")

 val actorObj1 = system.actorOf(Props[HelloWorld],"helloworld1")
 actorObj1 ! "Hi helloworld1"//first message sent

 val actorObj2 =system.actorOf(Props[HelloWorld],"helloworld2")
 actorObj2 ! "Hi helloworld2"//second message sent

}

}
```

**Code for Actor:**

```
import akka.actor.Actor

class HelloWorld extends Actor {

 def receive = {

case dataStr:String => println("Yes you made it "+dataStr)

}

}
```

Comment: Order of messages is guatanteed within the same actor, not between actors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka does not guarantee that messages are delivered in the order they are sent globally. It guarantees the following:

- at-most-once delivery (i.e. no guaranteed delivery, messages may be dropped)
- message ordering per sender–receiver pair

So you see, the ordering is only guaranteed for any given sender-receiver pair. If you send multiple messages from "helloworld1" they will be received in the order you sent them (however messages from other sources may come in between).

See [the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/message-delivery-reliability.html) for an in-depth explanation.